# Closed under finite unions (a,b]?

Tags: probability-theory

From Resnick, Probability, page 12.

Suppose $\Omega$ =R, and
*C*= finite intervals
={(a,b], -$\infty<a \leq b < \infty $}

According to the textbook, *C* is NOT closed under finite unions since (1,2]U(36,37] is not a finite interval.

I am not sure why this interval is not finite.

MY THOUGHTS: I thought because the union is of disjoint sets, then we cannot say this is of the form of (a,b].

However, in class  we saw that $\Omega$=(0,1] and *A*={$ \cup^{n}_{i=1}(a_i,b_i], 0\leq a_i \leq b_i \leq1 $}U{Null Set}

and we said that this is a field because the complement of finite open unions is an open finite intersection.

Can someone please give me a detailed explanation? Thank you very much.

Comment: $(1,2]\cup (36,37]$ is not an interval, because it's missing some points in the middle.

Comment: It is not a finite interval because it is not an interval.

Comment: "I am not sure why this interval is not finite."  It *IS* finite.  But it's not an interval.  So it isn't a finite interval.  It's a finite non-interval.  Which is just as unacceptable as an infinite interval would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Omega = \mathbb R$ and $C = \{all-finite-left-open-right-closed-intervals\}$ is not closed under finite unions becuase $(0,1] \cup (37, 256*\pi]$ is not a finite interval because, although it is finite, it is not an interval.

If $\Omega = (0,1]$ and $C = \{any-finite-union-of-left-open-rigth-closed-intervals-with-endpoints-between-0-and-1-inclusive-as-well-as-the-empty-set\}$ then this is an entirely different type of set.  It's elements are not intevals but finite unions of intervals.

It *is* closed under finite unions as any finite union of finite union of intervals smaller than or equal to (0,1] is a finite union of intervals smaller than or equal to (0,1].  It's a field because the complements are too.

Basically the two examples have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much! Now you mention it, yes, it makes sense: (a1,b1] and (a2,b2] and their union is inside A because of the way we defined the elements. As for n=2, (a1,b1]U(a2,b2] is also an element of the set.